# Infragistics - Automatically create data schema but binding manually

Tags: data-binding, infragistics

I'm new to infragistics. I have a database and a datalayer with entity framework and linq. Now I want to get the data to an Infragisticscontrol, let's use a UltraCombo. I have not problem to bind the data to the control. My problem is that all properties from the linqquery is displayed.
As far as I can see there are two options

1) Create a data schema manually. In this way there is much effort put in creating the schema and when I refactor something then the schemas of all controls must be updated.

2) Creating a data schema automatically.

I played a bit with the secand case but can'T find an option how to create the data schema automatically but binding the data manually. I had one case where I bound it to a model of the entity framework and deleted the datasource later from the project. In this case it worked but I don't think that this is the right way to use it.

Can somebody tell me how to do this or what's the best practice?

Comment: Have you tried with code? eg: **InitializeLayout**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in the Infragistics forum below. Here's the link: http://blogs.infragistics.com/forums/p/24379/89509.aspx